# What is the etymology of the term “creamy layer” in Indian politics?

Tags: etymology, subcontinental-english

According to Wikipedia, “[creamy layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creamy_layer) is a term used in Indian politics to refer to members of a [backward class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_class) who are highly advanced socially as well as economically and educationally, and not eligible for government-sponsored educational and professional benefit programs.”

What is the etymology of this term? Not being a speaker of Indian English, the words “creamy” and “layer” both strike me as unusual descriptors for classes of people. Is there a connection to the idiom “cream of the crop”?

Comment: Isn't this what Americans call being in the donut hole? I picture an Oreo cookie's creamy middle, as the poor who are advanced are still poor yet not *poor enough* to quailify for assistance.

Comment: That term is also new to me! This seems to be something different, though, as it includes people who are potentially very wealthy (ie. would not fall in the donut hole) but are members of a backward class by reason of their caste, which is inherited.

Comment: Looking into this aspect of the Indian caste system is a bit like trying to figure out how the Holocaust came about, or how sausages are made. Not for the squeamish!

Comment: ...but the usage will almost certainly derive "directly" from the more *literal* sense of the layer of cream that "floats" to the surface in a container filled with milk, not by further extension from the already far more metaphorical ***cream of the crop***. Expressions like [***the cream of society***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+cream+of+society&year_start=1750&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) (the social elite, who rise to the top) have been around for centuries.

Comment: ["The term creamy layer was first coined by Justice Krishna Iyer in 1975 in State of Kerala vs NM Thomas case..."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Other_Backward_Class#Legal_disputes). Wikipedia also explains what it is supposed to mean.

Comment: If the Wikipedia article itself isn't enough, it provides a lot of references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Justice Krishna Iyer of India first used the term in a 1975 court case. The "creamy layer" is the top layer of the Other Backward Class, which might receive a disproportionate amount of the benefits of a quota (reservation) system ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creamy_layer)).

The phrase is very likely a metaphor that relies on the physical phenomenon of *cream* rising to the top of raw milk (naturally) or other substances like coffee (after cream has been added, over time) (see Wikipedia, "[Cream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cream)"). This substance is particularly rich in fat and flavor compared to the rest of the milk, which makes it form a layer at the top (from The Prairie Homestead, "[How to Separate Cream from Milk](https://www.theprairiehomestead.com/2015/03/separate-cream-from-milk.html)":

[image]

That is literally a creamy layer!

Incidentally, *cream* has been used figuratively to mean *the best* in English since the 16th century (Oxford English Dictionary, "[cream, n.2](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/44024)," def. 3). So there is also a bias in English to think of cream in a superlative sense, especially in the later idiom *the cream of the crop*.